# Error Memory Size in Yireo Email Tester

Tags: magento-1.9, error, memory

`/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php`

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 95 bytes) in /lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291

How do I fix this issue, do I need to set a **memory limit** ?

Any suggestions would be greatly thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much for your help on this. I was able to figure this out by simply editing my php.ini on local/shared hosting environment. works great now!

Comment: If you used one of the answers provided, please mark is at the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sure!

It seems some database query of Yireo module needs more than 512Mb php memory_limit

You'd increase that php parameter, or maybe (better) debug that concrete query, so you can optimize it

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line to your .htaccess (for testing):

```
php_value memory_limit 1024M
```

This 1024M value assumes you have 1gb of memory available. You can adjust the amount accordingly for more or less memory to be used.

You can also add this line to your php.ini file which does the same thing:

```
memory_limit = 1024M
```

If you have CPanel installed, you can go to your PHP Variables Manager, select the folder that your site is in, add the variable `memory_limit` then enter 1024 (or your desired amount), then click "Save"